# Add new element below existing element using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an element Name "Dispute" and want to add new element name "Records" below the element.
Eg: The current XML is in this format using ssis technology

```
            <root>
            <Grade></Grade>
            <Fuel>
                <Quantity/>
                <Additional/>
                <Dispute>0</Dispute>
            </Fuel>
            <Fuel>
                <Quantity/>
                <Additional/>
                <Dispute>1</Dispute>
            </Fuel>
            </root>
            
            
            Need to add new element under dispute.

            <root>
            <Grade></Grade>
            <Fuel>
                <record>1</record>
                <Quantity/>
                <Additional/>
                <Dispute>0</Dispute>
                
            </Fuel>
            <Fuel>
               <record>2</record>
                <Quantity/>
                <Additional/>
                <Dispute>1</Dispute>

            </Fuel>
            </root>
```

XSLT did not work to add record element with attribute value 1 and 2

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
               <!-- Identity transform -->
               <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
                  <xsl:copy>
                     <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
                  </xsl:copy>
               </xsl:template>

               <xsl:template match="Dispute">
               <Dispute>0</Dispute>
               copy-of select="."/>
                  <record>1</record>
               </xsl:template>

               <xsl:template match="Dispute">
               <Dispute>1</Dispute>
               copy-of select="."/>
                  <record>2</record>
               </xsl:template>
            </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Dispute">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <record>
        <xsl:number count="Fuel"/>
    </record>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You did not specify the exact logic for populating the added `record` element. The above example will use sequential numbers.

---

### Added:

> I want record element just below the fuel element

You could restate that as "just before the `Quantity` element" and simply replace the 2nd template with:

```
<xsl:template match="Quantity">
    <record>
        <xsl:number count="Fuel"/>
    </record>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Or you could change the strategy and use:

```
<xsl:template match="Fuel">
    <xsl:copy>
        <record>
            <xsl:number/>
        </record>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: how I move this 

       <root>
       <Grade></Grade>
       <Fuel>
        <record>1</record>
        <Quantity/>
        <Additional/>
        <Dispute>0</Dispute>

       </Fuel>
       <Fuel>
        <record>2</record>
        <Quantity/>
        <Additional/>
        <Dispute>1</Dispute>                
       </Fuel>
       </root>

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. P.S. Please do not post code in comments, it's difficult to read.

Comment: michael.hor257k - soory, I want the root element at top, I have changed the xml file as well

Comment: How is the result here different from the result you want? https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNP54dF

Comment: I want record element just below the fuel element

Comment: See the addition to my post. Next time please do not change the requirements after your question has been answered.

Comment: Thank you michael.hor257k